# Alternative to Firefox and Chrome with an element inspector?

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, web-development, web-browser

Assuming that

- [Mozilla is not trustworthy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMALm1VthGY),
- Chrome isn't any better, because Google …,
- Chromium isn't any better just because it's open source, after all Firefox is open source,

is there any browser that:

- is trustworthy
- is open source, free and none profit
- works on Linux (I'm on Fedora)
- supports basic extensions like ad-blocker and LastPass
- has an element inspector for programmers like me
- is fast, and relatively lightweight?

Comment: Funny last week I dumped chrome for quantum, and wanted to donate to mozilla on a monthly basis and then i watch that video :)

Comment: Isn't not trusting Mozilla and using LastPass a bit shizoprenic ?!

Comment: @RoVo true, considered dumping lastpass many times, I will soon, now I had many websites depending on it, installed it when it was secure, before it got hacked that is, but now I got a long list of websites, migrating to another password manager might take very long time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with "trustworthy" is that trust isn't something one can be recommended to...it's something that you gotta have. (I didn't watch the video but I'm sure you can technically do a rant about just any application/OS developer based on some mess ups...)

But what I would suggest is taking a look on some of the more popular browsers based on the Chromium project as well as on the Mozilla browser project, but not controlled in any way by these big corporations/organizations.

On the Chromium end of things, there's [**Brave**](https://brave.com/) and [**Vivaldi**](https://vivaldi.com/?lang=en_US). While from Firefox there are [**Pale Moon**](https://www.palemoon.org/) and [**Waterfox**](https://www.waterfoxproject.org/).